# How to store a time interval with HH:MM:SS:MS swift

Tags: swift, time, formatter

So this turned out to be way more complex than I was I expecting. I have four text fields that allows the user to enter HH:MM:SS:MS and I need to mash these together to create a number I can save in fireStore.

I then need to get this number out and convert it back to HH:MM:SS:MS again for use in a tables graphs etc.

I did initially consider using a string but that's not going to help me with graphs/ordering I want to do later. Done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find a workable solution that includes milliseconds.

Any help appreciated!

Some code below if that helps, all I have at the moment is me mashing these together into a string...

```
let goalHHText = UITextField()
let goalMMText = UITextField()
let goalSSText = UITextField()
let goalMSText = UITextField()

let goalCombined.append(goalHHText.text! + ":" + goalMMText.text! + ":" + goalSSText.text! + ":" + goalMSText.text!)
```

I'm then adding goalCombined into a dictionary and pushing into Firestore. Sorry that's as far as I've got, I am 100% coding noob.

I've looked at dateComponentsFormatter but that doesn't support milliseconds

```
let interval = 27005
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second ]
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(interval))!
print(formattedString)
```

Comment: You should look into DateComponents and/or DateComponentsFormatter

Comment: I've looked at date components @JoakimDanielson but it doesn't support milliseconds, I have built to convert seconds, but I need milliseconds

`code`let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second ]
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(interval))!
print(formattedString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it into smallest unit time, here milliseconds. Convert the entire time to milliseconds by :-

```
index = (((HH*60 + MM)*60 + SS)*60 + MS)*1000;
```

Store 'index' value in firestore as type "number". Also store individual HH, MM, SS, MS values separately in firestore for easy retrieval.

Comment: Thanks @HarisWilson so is there a way to convert this back into HH MM SS MS? I was looking at a similar solution using a date formatter but it doesn't support milliseconds...
`code`
let interval = 27005
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second ]
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(interval))!
print(formattedString)

Comment: Also If you store the time exactly in this string format "HH:MM:SS:MS" there wont be any issue with ordering in firestore. You will get the intended results while ordering even though it is in strings. But every individual fields in the entries must have the same digits i.e. if your are using two digits for storing one hour you must use `01:00:00:000` instead of `1:0:0:0` and also your range will be confined to a max of `99:99:99:999` to `00:00:00:000`

Comment: Brilliant I was wondering if I even needed the conversion any more after you suggested saving it as strings. Just wasn’t sure if I could achieve ordering. Fantastic thank you I’ll give it a go

Comment: Why do you want to convert it back from the smashed value itself? When you store the smashed value into database also store the individual values so you can retrieve that values also whenever you are retrieving the smashed value keep it simple

Comment: I just presumed I was attempting to achieve some sort of date format that swift will recognise. In my mind that was going to enable me to manipulate the data (ordering, displaying in a graph - depending on what library I choose) more easily

Comment: Sometimes using libraries wont be the best way forward. Good Luck